# Recording coordinates of Scene view in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, bookmarks, local-scene

I am teaching my GIS class this year using ArcGIS Pro 2.0.  Some of the lessons involve using 3D scenes.  Is there a way for me to direct my students to a specific view of a scene for me to visually inspect a screenshot that they provide.  For example, I would like to be able to direct them to show me what their scene looks like at this particular location by entering the coordinates I give them for my scene, including elevation and azimuth, and comparing it to theirs:

[image]

I cannot determine how to record those values and then use something like the old "Go to" tool from ArcMap to find that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you could use a [Bookmark](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/bookmarks.htm) (with my bolding):

> A spatial bookmark identifies a specific geographic location (in 2D **or
>   3D**) that you want to save and refer to later.

Once you have created a bookmark at the view in your picture:

> [Bookmarks can be shared between projects as a bookmark file (.bkmx).](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/manage-bookmarks.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_D347604EA6C54321A023422E11EE9944)

You could then share that BKMX file with your students and ask them to import it, and then go to that bookmark:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To do this you could use the Camera Properties control, which is at the right hand end of the View tab on the ribbon.  When that is open you can see values for:

- X, Y and Z;
- Pitch;
- Roll; and
- Heading

You can copy these manually to give them to your students, or use the Copy Camera Settings button at the bottom of the Camera Properties control to copy them to the clipboard so that you can paste them into another application.

[image]

[image]